# How to add a record to the database if not all fields are filled?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my React app I do fetch to add row into database (PostgreSQL):

```
addToDatabase() {
 fetch(`${'127.0.0.1:3000'}/add`, {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: JSON.stringify(this.state.person),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
  ...
}
```

**this.state.person** usually has next format:

```
{id: 1, surname: 'Jones', name: 'John', city: 4}
```

On backend I use sequelize to add row to database:

```
app.route('/add')
  .put((req, res) => {
    Person.create({
      surname: req.body.surname,
      name: req.body.name,
      city: req.body.city      
    });
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));
  });
```

Sometimes I need to add a row with only surname. In this way, **this.state.person** has next format:

```
{id: 1, surname: 'Jones'}
```

But I get an error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

Backend always wait for all fields filled. How can I add record with selectively filled fields?

Comment: Can you pass null values? Have a default values object, merge that with the data you have and then create.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin when the user filled input on frontend, React add to this.state.person corresponding value (e.g. name: 'Test'). When user click save button, React call addToDatabase() with new object this.state.person. At which step I should add a default values object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

req.body.city will be set undefined and this will cause an error

```
Use NULL for "empty" values in a numeric column 
The empty string '' can only be used in character types like text or varchar
```

Comment: you can add default value in your database schema(model).